# Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\thara\.gradle\caches\transforms-

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build, expo, mobile-application

I'm new to react native. I develop a mobile app using expo. Then I tried to build my app with eas build.
It build normally. But after install the apk on my mobile, It stop running on splash screen.

Because of that reason, I moved to development build. It gives me this error.

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_slider:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_slider:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match 
attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, 
org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: 
C:\Users\thara\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-
for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\thara\.gradle\
caches\transforms-
3\89db9bcd56ab5312cc04ec9440ec4d21\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-
modules java.base --output C:\Users\thara\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\89db9bcd56ab5312cc04ec9440ec4d21\transformed\output\jdkImage --
disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

I tried these things which were found from the stackoverflow.

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    .........
    defaultConfig {
         ........
         minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
```

(In a same question, there are the answers says to add minSdkVersion 21, But my config is different. So i go to root build.gradle(**android/build.gradle**) and changed the minSdkVersion to 21)

Then i delete the build file and run `npx expo build:android` again.

But issue is not solved.

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace 'com.tharanga_sandun.MonkeyRepellent'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.tharanga_sandun.MonkeyRepellent'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging (findProperty('expo.useLegacyPackaging')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
        }
    }
}

// Apply static values from `gradle.properties` to the `android.packagingOptions`
// Accepts values in comma delimited lists, example:
// android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts=/LICENSE,**/picasa.ini
["pickFirsts", "excludes", "merges", "doNotStrip"].each { prop ->
    // Split option: 'foo,bar' -> ['foo', 'bar']
    def options = (findProperty("android.packagingOptions.$prop") ?: "").split(",");
    // Trim all elements in place.
    for (i in 0..<options.size()) options[i] = options[i].trim();
    // `[] - ""` is essentially `[""].filter(Boolean)` removing all empty strings.
    options -= ""

    if (options.length > 0) {
        println "android.packagingOptions.$prop += $options ($options.length)"
        // Ex: android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts += '**/SCCS/**'
        options.each {
            android.packagingOptions[prop] += it
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";
```

My root file
**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'

        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS, I solved it by

```
brew install openjdk@17
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Ensure openjdk version 17 is selected

```
$ echo $PATH

Ensure to see this lines
..:/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:
```

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.10+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.10+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

as noted [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/7053)